# Eleventy: Deploying static site into local file system

Tags: documentation-generation, eleventy, ssg

I have created a static site for my project documentation using Eleventy and want to deploy into local file system. I tried with many method but no luck.
Actually I want to upload the static site/pages into source repository and whoever downloads should be able to use/browse the documentation. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So running `eleventy` by itself will output, by default, your code to the `_site` folder. If you have a site using Eleventy already, then you're done. Just run the command and your output is there.

It sounds like you also want to *deploy* that site such that people can use it. That's a whole other topic. There are multiple places where you can deploy a Jamstack site using Eleventy: Netlify, Vercel, Amazon S3, etc. If you want to have a commit to a source repository deploy your site, I'd look at Netlify. They can connect to your repo and on updates, run the Eleventy command on your site and deploy the results.

Comment: Thanks Raymond for the response. You are right if I have a site using Eleventy it works perfectly fine. It works even without eleventy by directly opening the index,html file but navigation bar doesn't work as expected.
My requirement is if developer checkouts out the code then he/she should be able to browse without the help of eleventy.

Comment: Well, that's a bit different. Normally you do NOT check in the _site folder to your repo as it's supposed to be generated by Eleventy. But you certain can check it in. Then your developers check out the repo, browse to _site, and run a local web server. They can use httpster, a tool installed via npm that runs a local web server in a directory.

Comment: Looks like what I'm expecting is not possible. I will consider your solution. One last question, any idea how boost library documentation is generated which is bundled with package? I am looking something similar to that, apart from doxygen.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are asking. "boost library documentation" - what do you mean?

Comment: please ignore my last comment about boost library documentation. Thanks you.